# make mesh portal with geometry nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

IS it possible to make a portals ( planes ) which can be transition some vertices through the wall to the another plane?

Has anyone ever seen anything like this?:

[image]

Comment: tags: tile trim grabdoc bake

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Be aware of that you might have to change some values that it works for the size of your geometry!

This is my node tree:

[image]

result:

[image]

Comment: cool result! Thank you! actually i am trying to improve the GrabDoc addon </br>
Is it possible in this way to add offset on both sides so that the torn edges are not visible? </br>
It is necessary for the clear baking of the trims
[Screenshot](https://prnt.sc/hafqNnyWzV3j)

Comment: You are welcome. I think the higher the subdivision is the better will be the edges.

Answer (score 2):

The basic idea of "portal" is that when your objects move across (or past) a position (1st portal), the vertices on your objects are somehow **separated and translated to the opposite position (which is on the other side where the 2nd portal is located)**. This can be achieved if the things below are known:

a. The position of the 1st portal & 2nd portal. We can retrieve this using **2 Empties** as our controllers so that we'd be able to manipulate the position through the Empties.
[image]

b. The length/distance of all the presented vertices on your objects (which will be calculated from the world space's origin point [0,0,0]).
[image]

[image]

From **(a)**, you can use some vector math calculations to get:

- The distance from 1st portal -> 2nd portal.
- The directional vector which points from 1st -> 2nd portal.
  [image]

-> Once you get the **distance from 1st portal -> 2nd portal**, divide it by 2 to get the **distance limit threshold** which you'll need to be able to determine (at what distance/length) the vertices will be separated.
[image]

->Take that distance threshold and compare it with **(b)**. This will allow you to tell Blender only to separate those vertices that pass the portals.
[image]
Combine this with **the directional vector from portal 1st -> 2nd portal + the distance between the two**, you'll also be able to tell Blender to translate the separated vertices from before to the position of the 2nd portal.
In case the separation (or cut) is a bit "loose" or still has some remaining vertices left that haven't been fully separated, you can always adjust the threshold to "tighten" it a bit.

Here's the full setup.
[image]

The result:
[image]

In case you want to make these portals look a bit more interesting, here's a bit more advanced set-up where the object's twisted/bent once it gets closer to the portals.

[image]

I have also attached a blend file in case you want to take a look at it later.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help! but i cant download the Blend file

Comment: @SergeyIvanov Sorry about that and thanks for notifying me! I'd fixed the uploaded blend file, you can download it now.